# TYPO3 - BE ACL - Single record permissions?

Tags: permissions, acl, typo3, backend

I would like to give to BE user a permission to view/edit only one record of some type.

For example, I have lots of tt_address, and I would like to give a permission to some client to view/edit only his/her tt_addresses in the BE, records are situated in the same sysfolder.

Is it possible or I need to hook the core to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension for that job: http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/tm_contentaccess/current/ however didn't check it. I read on the [mailing list](http://typo3.3.n7.nabble.com/access-rights-of-single-data-records-td109839.html) that it's state in TYPO3 4.5+ is unverified.

If it won't work I wouldn't hack the core. Instead it should be quite easy task to write a backend module for listing/editing only selected items from given database table, so you can extend tt_address with field containing UID of the 'owner'.

Comment: The extension looks great ! I need FE edit too, so it could be too much  development instead of tiny hook on Core ACL. I think, will develop ACL extension instead of fake listing.